# Neo4J REST API Call Error - Error reading as JSON ''

Tags: java, json, rest, neo4j, cypher

this is a newo4j rest api call related error - from my java code I'm making a REST API call to a remote Neo4J Database by passing query and parameters, the query being executed is as below

```
*MERGE (s:Sequence {name:'CommentSequence'}) ON CREATE SET s.current = 1 ON MATCH SET s.current=s.current+1 WITH s.current as sequenceCounter MERGE (cmnt01:Comment {text: {text}, datetime:{datetime}, type:{type}}) SET cmnt01.id = sequenceCounter WITH cmnt01 MATCH (g:Game {game_id:{gameid}}),(b:Block {block_id:{bid}, game_id:{gameid}}),(u:User {email_id:{emailid}}) MERGE (b)-[:COMMENT]->(cmnt01)<-[:COMMENT]-(u)*
```

Basically this query is generating a sequence number at run time and sets the 'CommentId' property of the Comment Node as this Sequence number before attaching the comment node to a Game's block i.e. For every comment added by the user I'm adding a sequence number as it's id.

This is working for almost 90% of the cases but there are couple of cases in a day when it fails with below error

```
ERROR com.exectestret.dao.BaseGraphDAO - Query execution error:**Error reading as JSON ''**
```

Why does the Neo4J Query not return any proper error code ? It just says error reading as JSON ''.

Neo4J Version is

```
Neo4j Community Edition 2.2.1
```

Thanks,
Deepesh

Comment: Also to add, the dependency in pom.xml is the latest one i.e.  
                <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>

Repo as below
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>mvn-neo4j</id>
   <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/everything</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

Did searching in net on various posts, but still not able to find any proper info on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It gets HTML back and can't read it as JSON, but should output the failure HTML can you check the log output for that and share it too?

Also check your `graph.db/messages.log` and `data/log/console.log` for any error messages.